# How to hide few theme customization options - TwentySeventeen theme

Tags: theme-customizer

I am just trying to modify Twenty Seventeen theme by and I want to hide few customize options like **Header Media** and **Colors** how can I do it ?

[image]

I have researched it but it seems like the given options are unable to hide these menus.

Can someone give me a hook or something to be able to hide this please.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change `active` status of section using `customize_section_active` `filter`. It gives 2 parameters `$active`-`bool` and `$section`-`object`. Haven't tried it so you can try and see if works for you.

Located in `\wp-includes\class-wp-customize-section.php`, for your research.

As second option you can try altering capability for the section.

Note: I'm just giving options, and have not done any of these before. So not sure about it.

Comment: `customize_section_active` is a hook. Used to enable or disable a section. So in call back of it you can check your active theme and section id and disable which you want.